# 'rosdep update' sporadically working (Ubuntu 14.04, indigo, ARM)

Tags: ros, rosdep, update, jetson-tk1, jetson

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Installing indigo arm on jetson tegra tk1 using these instructions: (http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu).

I am at 'rosdep update' and it fails sporadically at different points.

I have tried reinstalling indigo.
I can resolve DNS/IP fine, and almost every file has both succeeded or failed.
I have tried to purge, update, reinstall rosdep (yes rosdep --version and apt-cache policy are the same).

Here is an example 2 runs:

RUN 1:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.10.40-gdacac96 armv7l)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Thu Dec  8 00:15:42 2016
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml]:
        Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
        <urlopen error timed out>
Query rosdistro index https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
ERROR: error loading sources list:
        <urlopen error <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml)>
```

RUN 2 (30 seconds later):

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Query rosdistro index https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
Add distro "groovy"
Add distro "hydro"
Add distro "indigo"
Add distro "jade"
ERROR: error loading sources list:
        <urlopen error <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/jade/distribution.yaml)>
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$
```

I did this as an example while I was running this and it was the furthest it has ever gotten.

Should I just wait for sunny days in the future where I will get lucky and everything will work? I would also like to note that the views on forum items with "rosdep update" all have >300 views so I am seeing an issue with this delivery method.

I also successfully dual-booted ubuntu 14.04 and installed indigo on a Mac last night at ~2 am so maybe I will wait for 2 am to come around.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249605/%27rosdep-update%27-sporadically-working-(ubuntu-14.04,-indigo,-arm)/) by [anonymous28754](https://answers.ros.org/users/28754/anonymous28754/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Github had a fairly substantial outage today that may have contributed to this: https://status.github.com/messages/2016-12-07

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0